# calculate path similarity score and list comprehension questions

Tags: python, nltk, list-comprehension, wordnet, synonym

I have two lists of synsets generated from wordnet.synsets():

```js
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import pandas as pd

#convert tag to the one used by wordnet
def convert_tag(tag):
    tag_dict = {'N': 'n', 'J': 'a', 'R': 'r', 'V': 'v'}
    try:
        return tag_dict[tag[0]]
    except KeyError:
        return None

#define a function to find synset reference
def doc_to_synsets(doc):
    token = nltk.word_tokenize(doc)
    tag = nltk.pos_tag(token)
    wordnet_tag = convert_tag(tag)
    syns = [wn.synsets(token, wordnet_tag) for token in nltk.word_tokenize(doc)]
    syns_list = [token[0] for token in syns if token]
    
    return syns_list

#convert two example text documents
doc1 = 'This is a test function.'
doc2 = 'Use this function to check if the code in doc_to_synsets is correct!'

s1 = doc_to_synsets(doc1)
s2 = doc_to_synsets(doc2)
```

I am trying to write a function to find the synset in s2 with the largest 'path similarity' score for each synset in s1. Hence, for s1, which contains 4 unique synsets, the function should return 4 path similarity scores, from which I will convert into a pandas Series object for ease of computation.

I have been working on this following code so far

```js
def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    list = []
    for word1 in s1:
        best = max(wn.path_similarity(word1, word2) for word2 in s2)
        list.append(best)
        
    return list
```

However, it only return an empty list without any values in it.

```
[]
```

Would anyone care to look at what's wrong with my for loop and perhaps enlighten me on this subject?

Thank you.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] in a single code snippet that we can instantly copy, paste, and run, including the function call and print.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the "Sysnet" class references since I don't have whatever that class is, and it doesn't matter for scoring purposes.  The score function is abstracted out so you can define it however you like.  I took a stab at a very simplistic rule.  It compares each position, demarcated by the `.` separators, to see if they are equal.  If they are, the score is incremented.  For example, in `s1`, `be.v.01` compared to a made up `be.f.02` would have a score of 1, because on the prefix matches.  If instead we compared to `be.v.02`, we would have a score of 2, etc.

```
s1 = [('be.v.01'),
('angstrom.n.01'),
('function.n.01'),
('trial.n.02')]

s2 = [('use.n.01'),
('function.n.01'),
('see.n.01'),
('code.n.01'),
('inch.n.01'),
('be.v.01'),
('correct.v.01')]

def score(s1,s2):
    score = 0
    for x,y in zip(s1.split('.'),s2.split('.')): 
        if x == y: 
            score += 1 
    return score

closest = [] # list of [target,best_match]

for sysnet1 in s1:
    max_score = 0
    best = None
    for sysnet2 in s2:
        cur_score = score(sysnet1,sysnet2)
        if cur_score > max_score:
            max_score = cur_score
            best = sysnet2
    closest.append([sysnet1,best])


print(closest)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. The desired function is based on path_similarity() which is a built-in function in wordnet. Synset objects are generated using the first code block.
I am having trouble writing a for loop to get a path similarity score from two sets of synset and whose length must equal the length of the first synset entering into the similarity_score() function.

Comment: Then try replacing score with that function.

Comment: I see your code example has completely changed since the first post - I'll have a look in a bit but have to run for now.  At first glance I don't see any obvious errors, but I would avoid naming variables after built-ins e.g. `list` in your example.

Comment: Yes, I tried to change that to token_list or something else.

Comment: I opened another question thread  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45967214/iterate-one-list-of-synsets-over-another), which might be more clear. I just couldn't figure out a way to iterate the two synsets over path_similarity().