# Iterate one list of synsets over another

Tags: python, for-loop, nltk, wordnet, synonym

I have two sets of wordnet synsets (contained in two separate list objects, s1 and s2), from which I want to find the maximum path similarity score for each synset in s1 onto s2 with the length of output equal that of s1. For example, if s1 contains 4 synsets, then the length of output should be 4.

I have experimented with the following code (so far):

```js
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import pandas as pd

#two wordnet synsets (s1, s2)

s1 = [wn.synset('be.v.01'),
 wn.synset('angstrom.n.01'),
 wn.synset('trial.n.02'),
 wn.synset('function.n.01')]

s2 = [wn.synset('use.n.01'),
 wn.synset('function.n.01'),
 wn.synset('check.n.01'),
 wn.synset('code.n.01'),
 wn.synset('inch.n.01'),
 wn.synset('be.v.01'),
 wn.synset('correct.v.01')]
 
# define a function to find the highest path similarity score for each synset in s1 onto s2, with the length of output equal that of s1

ps_list = []
def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    for word1 in s1:
        best = max(wn.path_similarity(word1, word2) for word2 in s2)
        ps_list.append(best)
    return ps_list

ps_list(s1, s2)
```

But it returns this following error message

```
'>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

I couldn't figure out what's going on with code. Would anyone care to take a look at my code and share his/her insights on the for loop? It will be really appreciated.

Thank you.

The full error traceback is here

```js
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-73-4506121e17dc> in <module>()
     38     return word_list
     39 
---> 40 s = similarity_score(s1, s2)
     41 
     42 

<ipython-input-73-4506121e17dc> in similarity_score(s1, s2)
     33 def similarity_score(s1, s2):
     34     for word1 in s1:
---> 35         best = max(wn.path_similarity(word1, word2) for word2 in s2)
     36         word_list.append(best)
     37 

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

[edit]
I came up with this temporary solution:

```js
s_list = []
for word1 in s1:
    best = [word1.path_similarity(word2) for word2 in s2]
    b = pd.Series(best).max()
    s_list.append(b)
```

It's not elegant but it works. Wonder if anyone have better solutions or handy tricks to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no experience with the nltk module, but from reading the docs I can see that path_similarity is a method of whatever object `wn.synset(args)` returns.  You are instead treating it as a function.

What you should be doing, is something like this:

```
ps_list = []
for word1 in s1:
    best = max(word1.path_similarity(word2) for word2 in s2) #path_similarity is a method of each synset
    ps_list.append(best)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks again for your reply. I added my temporary solution as new edit, but yours appears to be more elegant. Note that for your definition of 'best', Python will return an error 'float object is not callable', therefore I define 'best' as a list object and then convert it to pd.Series, then max(). Kinda tedious though...

Answer (score 1):

I think the error comes from the following:

```
best = max(wn.path_similarity(word1, word2) for word2 in s2)
```

you should add a condition if wn.path_similarity(word1, word2) is NoneType, then you cannot do  *max()* , for instance you can re-write like this:

```
best = max([word1.path_similarity(word2) for word2 in s2 if word1.path_similarity(word2) is not None])
```